# Can I move to US having telecommuting job?

Tags: usa, visas, money

Assuming I already have a job in my home country and I work at home. It pays great and I save some money. Also I am aware I can afford to live in US so can I move to US? Would I be able to open my bank account there to ask my employer to send money to US instead of my home country. Would I need to pay taxes? What visa I would need there?

Comment: Hi Umair Ashraf! This question sounds a lot like immigration. Unfortunately this is considered off topic here at travel SE.

Comment: Yeah. I googled "Travel Stack Exchange" and this was the first thing.

Comment: Just googled there's tag for it http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customs-and-immigration

Comment: Umair - that tag is for "a range of border control procedures (referred to as 'immigration' in most countries other than US) and import of goods."

Comment: Wish the tag could speak that much :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since we're not allowed to answer immigration questions, I'll keep it short with two things.

Any stay longer then 90 days requires a visa for immigration and anyone that stays 181 days or longer or there income is paid to a US company is required to pay taxes. However, if you did immigrate to the US and spent more then 181 days away from your home country, you would likely be exempt from paying taxes where you left.

Comment: My income is paid by European company. Can I go there for 90 days first and then apply for immigration, is that possible? I don't want to exempt taxes but I want to know if or not I would need to pay to put it in my expenses.

Comment: @UmairAshraf In your expenses?

Comment: Yeah to cut it from salary